# Compositions of $n$ with $r$ parts for every possible $r$ with parts no greater than 6 using generating function

Tags: combinatorics

I am starting with a generating function of the form $(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^r$.  I believe this is the correct approach but need a generating function that is a ratio of two polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6=x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)=x\frac{x^6-1}{x-1}\;.
$$

Comment: Actually now that I look at this wouldn't it be $x\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}$?

Comment: @user3798278: That's what I wrote -- you just multiplied both the numerator and the denominator by $-1$.